# Are these two "that" omissions the same situation?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

> This was a problem (that) he had to face.
>
> I find it a little odd (that) you don't get out much.

Are these two that-omission situations the same (e.g. regarding to parts of speech)? Why or why not?

Comment: What do you think? Do the sentences have the same structure in terms of what "that" is connecting?

Comment: @nschneid In the first sentence, I see a noun before that. In the second, it seems to be an adjective ... but I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, as you point out in the comment, the first one is in relation to a noun. It is a relative clause modifying a noun: *This was a **problem** [that he had to face]* (which implies *He had to face a problem*). "That" is completely optional in this relative clause.

In the second sentence I would say "that you don't get out much" is a clause functioning as a nominal with *it*-extraposition. Compare *I find **that you don't get out much** (to be) a little odd*—"that" is mandatory here. Omitting "that" as in *I find it a little odd you don't get out much* may be more informal.

Comment: To see the difference, replace "that" with "which." The first sentence still works, the second doesn't.

Comment: @AndyBonner That's a good test. Thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 1):

In either case, 'that' is not required. They are the same for omitting 'that'.

I don't know why however from the years of writing I have done, I know that you don't need 'That'.

However, I would say that not omitting it is not too bad. It makes sense but makes the sentences wordier.